# Text Editors Are Hiding Text

Tags: block-editor

When I bring up an existing Page or Post, the Gutenberg Editor displays the title, then flashes the text as if it were confined to the left side of the edit panel, then the panel goes blank (with a correct word count at the bottom of the panel). I have tried to disable Gutenberg, and if I succeeded (how would I know), it made no difference. I have installed the Classic Editor plugin and activated it, and whether I disable Gutenberg or not, the same thing happens. The only change I can generate is getting a "choice" of the Block Editor or the Classic Editor on my postings list. However, neither "choice" changes anything. Any ideas would be welcome; I am effectively locked out of my editorial duties.

Comment: Are you running the latest version of WordPress? Have you opened up your browser console to see if there are any errors?